# Argument Count error too few arguments to function php Laravel input into a database validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I created a database that I have generated using a seeder, however now I wish for a user to input data and have me be allowed to see it on screen and add it to the database.

I also get this error when I input data and hit submit. It says:

> ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::store(), 1 passed in
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php
> on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

http://localhost/inventories

This is my router, web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('pages.index');

Route::get('/inventories', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'index'])->name('index');

Route::get('/inventories/create',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'create']);

Route::post('/inventories',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class,'store']);
```

This is my Controller, InventoryController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class InventoryController
 */
class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get the list of inventories.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::all();
        return view('pages.inventories',[
            "inventories" => $inventories
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.create');
    }
    /**
     * @param StorePostRequest $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $inventory)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate();
        $request->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|value:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory = $request->query('title');
        $inventory = $request->query('description');
        $inventory = $request->query('price');
        $inventory = $request->query('in_stock');
        $name = $request->query('on_sale');

        return redirect()->route('/inventories');
    }
}
```

This is my Inventory.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'on_sale' => 'boolean',
    ];
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'price',
        'in_stock',
        'on_sale',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

And this is my create.blade.php file where the user can input data(works fine but get error when I hit submit):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Create Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Please fill in the blanks to create an inventory.</strong></h1>
    <p><a href="/">Click here</a> to go back to the homepage.</p>
    <p><a href="/inventories">Click here</a> to go to the generated inventory page.</p>

    <form action="/inventories" method="post">
        @csrf
        <label for="title">Enter an item name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" required /><br><br>

        <label for="description">Enter the item's description:</label>
        <textarea name="description" required></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="price">Enter the item's price:</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" required/><br><br>

        <label for="in_stock">Enter a number of items in stock:</label>
        <input type="number" name="in_stock" required/><br><br>

        <label for="on_sale">Enter yes/no if item is on sale:</label>
        <input type="text" name="on_sale" required/><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Any help would be useful as I am at a complete loss. I just wish to display the data that the user input on the inventories page and then add a message of whether it worked or didn't work so the user knows. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain better what your goal is? Is not that clear for me

Comment: Yeah, sure. When the user inputs data and hits submit I want a message to pop up saying it was successful or not, and display what they inputed in on the browser.

Comment: did you see this? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: and, if something went wrong, just reload the same view (edit/create) with @old
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652814/laravel-blade-old-input-or-default-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your store method requires an $inventory to be passed to it :

```
public function store(Request $request, $inventory)
```

but your route doesn't define a route parameter called $inventory :

```
Route::post('/inventories',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class,'store']);
```

so the error is telling you that there are too few arguments being passed (1 is passed) to the function (2 are expected). So first remove the extra parameter :

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

and then create a new inventory within the method before you start populating it with data :

```
$inventory = new Inventory();
$inventory = $request->query('title');
```

Comment: That's great thank you for your help. I did as you suggested and now I am told 1 argument is passed but two are expected.